# Count number of Columns with specific value in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am searching a way to countif rows in pandas. An example would be:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A': [x,y, z], 'B':[z,y,x], 'C': [y,x,z] })
```

I want to count the number of repetitions on each row and add it to new columns based on specific criteria:

```
Criteria 
C1 = x
C2 = y
C3 = z
```

In the example above, C3 will be [1,0,2] As there are one 'z' in row 0, no 'z' in row 1 and two 'z' in row 2.

The end table would look like:

```
A   B   C | C1  C2  C3
x   z   y |  1   1   1
y   y   x |  1   2   0
z   x   z |  1   0   2
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean:

```
df.join(df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1).fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C    x    y    z
0  x  z  y  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  y  y  x  1.0  2.0  0.0
2  z  x  z  1.0  0.0  2.0
```

Comment: if renaming is important one can dictionary  `d={'x': 'C1', 'y': 'C2', 'z': 'C3'}`, then rename before join: `df.join(df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1).fillna(0).rename(columns=d))`

Comment: On the mock data it worked, but on the dataset I am working the new columns are not x, y and z but the index column A, B, C

Comment: @RafaelCasteloBranco did you forget `axis=1` in `apply`?

Comment: copied and pasted. my dataframe is even df to not mistake there

Answer (score 1):

Can iterate through the values and sum across axis 1

```
df = pd.concat([df.eq(val).sum(1) for val in ['x', 'y', 'z']], axis=1)
```

---

```
    0   1   2
0   1   1   1
1   1   2   0
2   1   0   2
```

Then rename your column names accordingly.

For a more general solution, consider `np.unique` and using the `pd.Series.name` attr.

```
pd.concat([df.eq(val).sum(1).rename(val) for val in np.unique(df)], axis=1)
```

---

```
    x   y   z
0   1   1   1
1   1   2   0
2   1   0   2
```

And with some trivial tweaks, you can have your end table

```
map_ = {'x':'C1', 'y':'C2', 'z':'C3'}
df.join(pd.concat([df.eq(i).sum(1).rename(map_[i]) for i in np.unique(df)], 1))
```

---

```
    A   B   C   C1  C2  C3
0   x   z   y   1   1   1
1   y   y   x   1   2   0
2   z   x   z   1   0   2
```